# Can I send a released application with Eclipse directly to a device?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm in the process of doing testing that requires testing with the released build. The process I have of releasing an app to my device currently involves a rather complex set of steps, from exporting a released app in eclipse to emailing it to myself. Ideally, I'd like to find something almost as easy as just hitting the play button is for releasing an unsigned version. Is there a way to do this entirely from eclipse?

I should say, I don't mind going through the typing the password process, but I'd like to just automatically export the app upon compiling to the device.

Comment: Why not using ant or gradle on the command line?

Comment: @Michael: Inertia really. I'll take the command line if I have to, but I'd rather do it from eclipse if I can. As far as Ant, I've just done so much development in Eclipse that I hesitate to switch to anything else...

Comment: Maven is an excellent option as well

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto Eclipse is no longer the official IDE for Android dev. You might start looking into IntelliJ soon because that's what the latest IDE from Google uses. http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: @MattC: Hadn't heard that... In fact, it's still listed on the Android docs on the Hello World project... http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html

Comment: @MattC eclipse still is the official android IDE, Android Studio is still in beta and they even suggest going back to eclipse if you are having problem or are uncomfortable with use a beta product

Comment: @PersonArtPhoto you can still call ant from Eclipse if you're too scared of shell windows. In your ant script, you can make all necessary adb calls, if you have your keystore passwords in ant.properties you can build and deploy with a single button click.

Comment: Does your phone provide anything like (Samsung) Kies?  I use Kies to upload release versions to my phone after testing and it works flawlessly with one click.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it was still in beta. Myself and my coworkers had moved to IntelliJ CE about a year ago so I hadn't paid attention after the announcement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a good way to do this with Eclipse. The best way to do it is to use your release certificate as your debug certificate, giving it the appropriate password.

What I ended up doing was to familiarize myself with the command line. Essentially I exported the app, then uploaded it to my device using `adb -d install -r APP_NAME.apk`. That worked great!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [Genymotion's emulators](http://www.genymotion.com/).

Once you've gotten them up and running you can drag and drop the release APK directly to the emulator. And they're much faster than the usual emulators and allow the use of hardware acceleration as well.

Of course this isn't *exactly* what you're asking for since you'd be testing on an emulator but I'd thought it might help a bit...

Comment: This doesn't work because I actually need released builds on devices with Google Play. While Genymotion is faster, it doesn't have Google Play...