# Run app in eclipse using private certificate (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse

I implementing project using Google Games Service, to run this need an real (private) certificate.
The eclipse run button, use the debug certificate... The Google Games Service don't accept this certificate!!

It is possible to change this run function?
I need to run but, to don't use the debug certificate, instead use my private certificate!

Because, it is too difficult to send app, remove app, install app every time, only for testing...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503634/544198

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto That thread isn't correct, or is outdated. You can release directly to Android devices now with a self-signed certificate. You need to set the devices to allow untrusted content, and you won't be able to put it ont he Play store, but you can put it on your website and people can download from there. https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html

Comment: Self signed has been around since the beginning, but there are still debug/ release keys for signing.

Comment: I know to do it using adb command, but how do it using only eclipse? When I run an app, the eclipse compile and send the apk using DEBUG certificate... I am using Google Games Service, this API, need an private certificate, don't work in debug certificate, I don't need it to post in Google Play, I need it for only test my app several times in my device. How run one app in eclipse, but using private certificate? It's Possible?