# Trouble signing apk with desired certificate

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have a certificate that is signing my app when I say File -> Export. When I install the apk that way, it works. However, when I just run my app off eclipse while my phone is plugged in, it does not. So obviously it is being signed with another certificate.

How can I get eclipse to sign the apk with the same certificate that is used when exporting the apk?

[This person has the exact same problem as me, but no answer either...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23305578/run-app-in-eclipse-using-private-certificate-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it's signed with other certificate, it's using `~/.android/debug.keystore`. I don't know much about eclipse but in Android-Studio with new build system (gradle) its very easy to switch between signing certificates within different variants of an app (e.g. debug/relese even with combinations like free/premium). I don't know if it will work, maybe just replace in your users directory debug.keystore with your own?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It lead me in the right direction to solving my issue. I had to copy my release keystore. Then change the keystore name to "android", change the alias to "androiddebugkey" and the alias password to "android". Then I set that keystore as the custom debug key and it worked. Thank you very very much.

Comment: what are you referring with change the keystore to "android" the alias and the alias password? can you explain how did you get it?

Comment: Remember that this key will be used always by default when building. Doesn't matter what project and what IDE. You must came up with clever idea to replace keystore for different projects (maybe other build system like ant? or just good old copy/paste ;-)

Comment: @user2580401 Check out this link: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode In order to use a custom debug key, the keystore name and password must be android and the alias must be androiddebugkey or else eclipse won't let you use the key as the debug key. Also, the key name doesnt have to be debug.keystore. It's just the keystore alias and passwords that need to be changed.